How to assign remove events to dynamically created buttons?
I'm building an R Shiny app where I can dynamically add UI, and each UI has its own button to delete the UI.
Each button has its own name with the pattern of "delete[number]", such as delete1, delete2, delete34, etc. The number corresponds to the UI that is added - Widget1, Widget2, Widget34, etc.
I'm trying to observe when the action button is pressed, so I can delete the appropriate widget.
I'm following this answer here.
The issue I'm having is how to access the id of the button that is pressed.
Here is my current code:
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyjqui)
library(gridstackeR)
library(plotly)

#2b3940
ui <- fluidPage (
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gridstack.js/10.0.1/gridstack-all.min.js", type='module'),
    tags$script(HTML('
      let numFirstWidgets = 0;
      function addFirstWidget() {
        var grid = document.querySelector(\'.grid-stack\').gridstack;
        let ids = "widget" + numFirstWidgets;
        grid.addWidget(`<div class="grid-stack-item"><div class="grid-stack-item-content" id=${ids}></div></div>`, {h:3, w: 2});
        numFirstWidgets += 1;
      }
    '))
  ),
  grid_stack(id="mygrid"),
  actionButton("first_widget", "First Widget"),
  # plotlyOutput("plot"),
  title = "Gridstack Prototype"
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  numOfWidgets <- 0
  observeEvent(input$first_widget, {
    # browser()
    runjs("addFirstWidget();")
    insertUI(
      paste0("#widget", numOfWidgets),
      where = "afterBegin",
      tagList(
        actionButton(paste0("delete", numOfWidgets), "Delete This Panel"),
        plotlyOutput(paste0("plotly", numOfWidgets), height="100%")
      ),
      output[[paste0("plotly", numOfWidgets)]] <- renderPlotly({
        plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
      })
    )
    numOfWidgets <<- numOfWidgets + 1
  })
  
  observeEvent(
    lapply(
      names(input)[grep("delete[0-9]+",names(input))],
      function(name){
        input[[name]]
      }
    ),
    {
      removeUI(paste("widget", gsub("[^0-9]", "", name)))
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

However, this doesn't work, as it gives me the error:
Warning: Error in is.factor: object 'name' not found
How do I get the specific name of the input so I can use it to remove the corresponding UI? There can be an unlimited number of actionButtons.

Please edit your answer and add a complete reproducible example. Not only the server should be included.

We don't have access to "www/app.css", please edit again (including only necessary css in order to keep it minimal).

@Jan I hope it works now, sorry about the issues

You don't need to use removeUI and the observeEvent here, it's simpler: When you create the actionButton for the deletion, pass an onclick parameter which removes the relevant widget:
actionButton(
  paste0("delete", numOfWidgets),
  "Delete This Panel",
  onclick = paste0(
    "var $ToDelete = $('#widget",
    numOfWidgets,
    "'); setTimeout(function(){$ToDelete.remove();},0);"
  )
)


